# Salto de linea en c#

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente código el cual es el body que se enviara a un correo y necesito que se envie con salto de linea, para ello use System.Environment.NewLine, pero se envia todo junto:

```
SOLICITUD PERSONA:60400 - Juan Martinez STATUS: ANTIGUO ESTADO: JALISCO... ETC
```

Y necesito que vea asi:

```
SOLICITUD 
PERSONA:60400 - Juan Martinez 
STATUS: ANTIGUO 
ESTADO: JALISCO
... ETC




string sql = "SELECT nombre FROM FUsuarios WHERE Nombre = '" + Session["Nombre"] + "'";
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
string nombre = Convert.ToString(cm.ExecuteScalar());
MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
MailAddress fromMail = new MailAddress("remitente@gmail.com");
Msg.From = fromMail;
Msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("destinatario@gmail.com"));

Msg.Subject = nombre;
Msg.Body += "SOLICITUD" + System.Environment.NewLine;
Msg.Body += "PERSONA:" + cod.Text + " - " + nom_prod.Text + System.Environment.NewLine;
Msg.Body += "STATUS: " + Status.SelectedValue + System.Environment.NewLine;
...ETC               

Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
string sSmtpServer = "";
sSmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
SmtpClient a = new SmtpClient();
a.Host = sSmtpServer;
a.Port = 587;
a.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
("remitentet@gmail.com", "password");
a.EnableSsl = true;
a.Send(Msg);
con.Close();             
return true;
```

Comment: Como es el tipo de mail que mandas (html? plano?) y como lo envias, el problema esta ahi, ese string es correcto para tu idea.

Comment: @gbianchi ya edite el codigo

Comment: Si es un html, entonces debes de reemplazar el `System.Environment.NewLine` por `"<br/>"`.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa es lo que va ;) Fijate que estas mandando el mail como html (por eso te pregunte el formato). La segunda parte de la respuesta que te dieron es correcta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si se trata de texto plano:

```
Msg.Body += "SOLICITUD \n";
Msg.Body += "PERSONA:" + cod.Text + " - " + nom_prod.Text + "\n";
Msg.Body += "STATUS: " + Status.SelectedValue;
```

Si es HTML

```
Msg.Body += "SOLICITUD <br/>";
Msg.Body += "PERSONA:" + cod.Text + " - " + nom_prod.Text + "<br/>";
Msg.Body += "STATUS: " + Status.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estas definiendo el `body` del mail como `html` porque no usas este para aplicar formato al texto

```
string sql = "SELECT nombre FROM FUsuarios WHERE Nombre = @nombre";
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", Session["Nombre"].ToString())
string nombre = Convert.ToString(cm.ExecuteScalar());

MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
MailAddress fromMail = new MailAddress("remitente@gmail.com");
Msg.From = fromMail;
Msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("destinatario@gmail.com"));

Msg.Subject = nombre;
string body = @"<p>SOLICITUD</p>
                <p>PERSONA: {0} - {1}</p>
                <p>STATUS: {2}</p>"

body = string.Format(body, cod.Text, nom_prod.Text, Status.SelectedValue);

Msg.Body = body;               

Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

//resto codigo
```

Usa siempre parametros en el query que ejecutes, no concatenes en el string

Para definir el html puedes usar `<p>` o sino `<br>`, la idea es tener el template y reemplazar los valores en las posiciones